# How do I call a Win32 Function in PowerShell 1.0 using P/Invoke?

Tags: winapi, powershell, pinvoke

There are many scenarios where it would be useful to call a Win32 function or some other DLL from a PowerShell script. to Given the following function signature:

```
bool MyFunction( char* buffer, int* bufferSize )
```

I hear there is something that makes this easier in PowerShell CTP 2, but I'm curious how this is **best done in PowerShell 1.0**. The fact that the function needing to be called  ***is using pointers*** could affect the solution (yet I don't really know).

So the question is what's the best way to write a PowerShell script that can call an exported Win32 function like the one above?

**Remember for PowerShell 1.0.**

Answer (score 5):

To call unmanaged code from Powershell, use the Invoke-Win32 function created by Lee Holmes. You can find the source [here](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/GetTheOwnerOfAProcessInPowerShellPInvokeAndRefOutParameters.aspx). There you can see an example of how to call a function that has pointers, but a more trivial usage would be:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Win32 "msvcrt.dll" ([Int32]) "puts" ([String])  "Test"
Test
0
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any mechanism in PowerShell 1.0 to directly call Win32 API's. You could of course write a C# or VB.NET helper class to do this for you and call that from PowerShell.

Update: Take a look at -

http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583236.aspx
http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/ManagingINIFilesWithPowerShell.aspx