# Get LastWriteTime of SymLink's Target

Tags: datetime, powershell

`(Get-Item $SymLink).LastWriteTime` return's the SymLink's last modified time and not the target's modified time.

How do I get the target's last modified time?

Comment: You should make that update a question answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be no direct way, thus for now this will have to be done in two steps-

1. Get the *path* of the SymLink's target
2. Get the LastWriteTime from the target's path

To determine if its a symlink: [Check if SymLink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818054/483588) - PowerShell
To get the path:

1. use the `Dir` command's *summary* output - from which the target information can be snipped out - using RegEx.
2. or using Native API Call: [GetFinalPathNameByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364962%28VS.85%29.aspx); see: [Calling Unmanaged Code
   from PS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/142516/483588)